# How to get click events from plugins working in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile

I've noticed that many plugins (such as simplemodal) that work fine in a desktop browser do not work fine on the iPad with jQuery Mobile. Simplemodal has a close button that fails to work, and I believe it's because the event listener needs to be for "tap." Is there some easy way I can tell all my jQuery plugins to respond to tap instead of click?

Answer (score 1):

You could always modify the plugin to look for tap when needed based on browser and device.

Or you could figure out the id or class of the button or any-other thing that needs tap and manually call the click event when tap is called.

```
$(id).tap(function(){
  // Now call click event
  $(id).click();
})
```